# Multiple users and iterations

Tags: loops, jmeter

I have the following scenario with concurrent users doing multiple iterations(eg 3 users and 2 iterations) and each iteration data is different and each data is relevant to a particular user only.

For example,

> user 1 is logging and booking 2 flight tickets and at the same time user 2 also logging and booking another 2 flight tickets. Similarly users 3 also booking.

I know in Load Runner this can be handled easily with parameter settings.

How to do this is JMeter?

Following is my parametrization data from the csv file.

User name, password,passport num,first name, last name,age[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIR9F.jpg)
user1,test123, A2000XB, John, Xavier,50
user1,test123, B2000XS, Sam, David,65
user2,test123, C2000XM, Sarah, Matt,50
user2,test123, D2000XB, Jim, David,43
user3,test123, K2000XV, Sarah, Matt,50
user3,test123, D2000XQ, Jim, David,43

user1 log on to the application and doing booking for passport numbers A2000XB and B2000XS and then log out. Similarly user2 log on to the application and doing booking for passport numbers C2000XM and D2000XB and then log out.Similarly user3 log on to the application and doing booking for passport numbers K2000XV and D2000XQ and then log out. All these users logging and doing the bookings at the same time.

The number of users and the number of bookings need to be configurable at any time. (csv file can modify accordingly).

Please refer the link for csv data.

Answer (score 0):

Add a thread group set number of threads to 5 loop count to 2 (5 users doing same scenario 2 times) and add to the thread group -> Config Element -> CSV Data set config to the thread group. 
[You can use CSV Data set config to fill out the different users test data](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
Another option is to use the config element User Defined Variables or add them to the Test Plan

Also make sure you have added Config Element -> Cookie manager to the thread group so you can store the sessions of the users
If the users are doing different scenarios you can use more than one thread group with different scenarios in each

[Test plan picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0kgm.png)

Comment: A single user needs to book 2 tickets without logging out.So there is only one log on and then do 2 bookings for different passengers and then log out. Similarly all the other users do bookings for different passengers at the same time.

Comment: Maybe i don't get it. Ok so make a thread group and add a sampler for logging then another sampler for booking then another sampler for booking again then logging out sampler for each user. (check the picture i have attached)

Comment: Boyan, Thanks for your response.
The concurrent users and iterations need to be dynamic so that i can test with any number of users and iterations.But I can modify the csv file with required number of data.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve:

- [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function - returns number of current thread
- [${__BeanShell(vars.getIteration())}](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__BeanShell) - returns the current loop number (on [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level)
- [__counter()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) function is incremented each time it's being called either individually for each user or globally
- you can read data from files using i.e. [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) or [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#_StringFromFile) functions

Actually there are multiple approaches, elaborate your question providing example of parametrization data and how you would like it to be used so we could advice. In the meantime I would recommend getting familiarized with [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) articles series

Comment: Modified the question with parametrization data.